# Adicionar input button num select

Tags: html

Quero um button para chamar outra pagina dentro de um select. O problema é que utilizando esse codigo, o button fica sempre fora do select.

```
<select>
  <option>teste</option>
  <option><input type=button value="Teste2"/></option>
</select>
```

Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/r82v3vxn/

Comment: Por um botão dentro de uma select não dá... Podes manipular a option da select com css para ficar idêntica a um botão

Comment: "Idêntica" não sei, mas parecida é mesmo possível. Acho que essa sua sugestão daria uma resposta, @CesarMiguel ;)

Answer (score 3):

Os elementos `<option>` não aceitam HTML, somente texto. Se quer criar um dropdown com opções visualmente mais sofisticadas, terá de simular seu próprio `<select>` usando outros elementos HTML, mais JavaScript.

Talvez este plugin de jQuery resolva pra você: http://pioul.fr/jquery-simpleselect

Answer (score 0):

Nao é possivel adicionar um`<button>` dentro de um select nativamente. Você consegue esse resultado com javascript simulando um select.